# How to fix a mail notifcation menu

Tags: menu, notification, notify-osd, libnotify

I'm getting a menu like this, don't know why.

[image: Rare menu]

I` M Using The 12.10

I Installed Some Notifcations

And Tried To Move The Notification Applets

Actually The Theme I`m Using Is Ambience-Dark

Some Thing Went Wrong From That Time

All The Menus Are Appearing Like These Getting some Border Arouund the Text And Background Colour is White

Comment: I just edited your post, as for some reason the image formatting was wrong. Also, please add more information: what version are you using? 12.04, 12.10... Are you using Unity?

Comment: Check Out My Promblem Now :)

Comment: And yeA i`m Using Unity